# Run mutex, but fails to create multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to simulate a server/client socket communication, and using threads for each client and then use mutex to lock and unlock those clients.

Mutex is working fine, even if I open another terminal and run the client script, it gets blocked till server unlocks it, but for some bad coding reason, this second client gets the same ID from the first client.

So, I want to create a new thread every time I run a new client. But I think that this "fork" is being the problem, for some reason...

```
int counter = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
void* operacoes (void*);
pthread_mutex_t mutexA = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t thread_id [10];
int var;
int jo = 0;
int t = 0;
int main()
{
    int sock_fd, sock_len, sock_novo, sock_novo_len,num;
    struct sockaddr_un sock_ser, sock_cli;
    char msg[100];

    sock_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sock_fd<0)
    {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    exit(0);
    }
    unlink("socket.unix.teste");
    bzero((char*)&sock_ser, sizeof(sock_ser));
    sock_ser.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(sock_ser.sun_path,"socket.unix.teste");
    sock_len = strlen(sock_ser.sun_path) +sizeof(sock_ser.sun_family);
    if(bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&sock_ser,sock_len)<0)
    {
    printf("ERROR\n");
    exit(0);
    }

    listen(sock_fd,5);

    for(;;)
    {
    sock_novo_len = sizeof(sock_cli);
    sock_novo = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_cli,&sock_novo_len);

    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        close(sock_fd);
        num = atoi(msg);

        counter++;
        for (i = jo; i<counter; i++)
        {
        pthread_create (&thread_id[i], NULL, operacoes, (void *)num);        
        jo++; 
        }
        for (j = t; j<counter; j++)
        {
        pthread_join(thread_id[j], NULL);;
        t++;
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    close(sock_novo);
    }
    return 0;
}

void* operacoes (void *arg)
{
    if(arg == 1)
    {
        int id = pthread_self();
        printf("Thread nummber: %d \n", id);
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexA);
        printf("Locked\n");
        sleep(10);      
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexA);
        printf("Unlocked\n");   
    }
return 0;
}
```

On client side, I only send a single variable 'msg'.

How could I solve it? I tried to use those two variables 'jo' and 't', but every new client I create, it reads the whole code, and it gets back to 0 so I cant get next phthread_create's vector position.

Comment: `fork()` creates a new *process*, not a new *thread*. Use `std::thread`.

Comment: A PThread-ID might very well be *unique to a process only*.

Comment: So should I create a thread and then threads of this thread? I don't know about c++(std::thread), do you know how could I do it in C? Thanks guys!!

Comment: If you want a C solution then why is the question tagged C++?

Comment: @Maet Mataias : Currently you create a new process with `fork` and then inside it a second thread using `pthread_create` . For concurrency, you only need either a new process or a new thread. Decide for one Option.

Comment: I used this "unlink" because I followed a book where it teaches how to do a socket communication, so no special reasons to use it. @JesperJuhl I thought you knew C too, sorry :).

Comment: @MichaelBeer hmm, got it, I will try to do it, because it looks confusing for me, to create something on "connection level" I mean, I'm not sure what I've to remove to turn it in full threads

Comment: OK, just try without your fork - call ... And remove the `unlink`

Comment: remove `if(fork() == 0) { close(sock_fd);` and the closing bracket...
And get yourself familiar with processes vs. threads ;)

Comment: @MichaelBeer Removing "unlink" it fails to bind. And removing the if(fork==0) condition, the second client doesn't run, because I think I should replace if for(something I don't know, maybe be threads, but dont know how)

Comment: However, I doubt that the Programm will do what you want - whenever a new connection arrives, you create several threads, block your entire Server until the threads are done, close the connection and only afterwards become ready for a new one. Usually you want multithreading to serve several connection at once?

Comment: You could try to remove the Form, don&amp;#39;t join on your threads, remove the thread_id array, and have the client socket closed in the thread (your `operacoes` function ... Then you had one thread per connection, probably what you want...

Comment: removing "close(sock_fd)" still doesnt allow the second client. Kind of... I think. I want to create a new thread for each new connection, and the those threads will "fight" or "dispute" for a system functionality, as edit a file, for example, and then other clients will wait mutex unlock to access this file.

Comment: I've changed thread_id array to pthread thread_id; and now it is now running the thread anymore, not even a single time. @MichaelBeer

Comment: @MartMataias I think if only create a thread to handle a client just after the accept() call, it should work fine. Then you are not required to close sock_fd.

Comment: @Soumen it is the problem, I think I undestood how to create a thread, and how to use mutex to lock and unlock things, but It seems strange for me to create a thread to handle a connection, because a thread calls a functions, but how to do it for the client, this is what i'm getting confused.

Comment: @MartMataias You are right with the `unlink`. I oversaw that you deal with UNIX domain sockets here ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand correctly what you want to achieve:

1. Create a unix domain socket and listen for incoming connections
2. Treat each connection in parallel
3. Have one global mutex being locked/unlocked during treatment of the connections

try this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutexA = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct oarg_t {
    int con_socket;
};

void* operacoes (void *arg)
{

    struct oarg_t* oarg = arg;
    int id = pthread_self();
    printf("Thread number: %d \n", id);
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexA);
    printf("Locked\n");
    sleep(10);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexA);
    printf("Unlocked\n");

    close(oarg->con_socket);
    free(oarg);

    return 0;

}

int main()

{

    const char* domain_name = "socket_unix.teste";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int sock_fd;

    sock_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sock_fd<0) goto error;
    unlink(domain_name);

    struct sockaddr_un sock_ser = {
        .sun_family = AF_UNIX,
    };

    strncpy(sock_ser.sun_path, domain_name, sizeof(sock_ser.sun_path));

    if(0 != bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &sock_ser, sizeof(sock_ser)))
        goto error;

    listen(sock_fd,5);

    size_t counter = 0;

    while(1) {

        struct sockaddr_un sock_cli = {0};

        int sock_len = sizeof(sock_cli);
        int sock_novo =
            accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_cli, &sock_len);

        if(0 > sock_novo) {
           printf("Error accepting:% s\n", strerror(errno));
           continue;
        }

        printf("Connection no %zu\n", counter++);

        struct oarg_t* oarg = calloc(1, sizeof(struct oarg_t));
        oarg->con_socket = sock_novo;

        pthread_t id = 0;

        pthread_create (&id, NULL, operacoes, oarg);

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

error:

    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```